# GA4 Measurement Protocol does not display user data (location, screen_resolution, language, etc.)

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

When I use the GA4 Measurement Protocol directly through HTTPS requests without Firebase or gtag.js, Google Analytics does not show any user-info such as screen resolution, location, language, etc., which I try to pass with user_properties or events. Maybe I'm using the wrong tags or the wrong place to pass these variables?

I've tried to use sr/screen_resolution, ul/location/country/geoid, language/lg, ...

How to pass these variables and in which format manually? Firebase and gtag collect them automatically, but since I do not use them (and do not advise to use them), I wonder how to do that in the right way.

I also tried to register these properties with custom definitions, but that did not help.
[image]

Comment: I have a same problem. Does you find solution?

Comment: No, did not find any :c

Answer (score 3):

The [measurement protocol for ga4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4) is extremely limited it will not let you send all of the reserved events sent by firebase, google tag Manager or any other the other google created systems.

You can send location asdocated with an item but thats about it

[send event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference/events#send_event_2)

```
items": [
      {
        "item_id": "SKU_12345",
        "item_name": "Stan and Friends Tee",
        "affiliation": "Google Merchandise Store",
        "coupon": "SUMMER_FUN",
        "currency": "USD",
        "discount": 2.22,
        "index": 0,
        "item_brand": "Google",
        "item_category": "Apparel",
        "item_category2": "Adult",
        "item_category3": "Shirts",
        "item_category4": "Crew",
        "item_category5": "Short sleeve",
        "item_list_id": "related_products",
        "item_list_name": "Related Products",
        "item_variant": "green",
        "location_id": "ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo",
        "price": 9.99,
        "quantity": 1
```

Things like screen resolution, language.. can not be sent directly through the measurement protocol they are automatically sent when you use the supplied sdks.    From my understanding from the team (I have been asking since it was released)  there are no plans to allow the measurement protocol to be able to send all the the standard reserved intermal event data.